# Is it possible to specify which takstrackers to use in a MapReduce job?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs

We have two types of jobs in our Hadoop cluster. One job uses MapReduce HBase scanning, the other one is just pure manipulation of raw files in HDFS. Within our HDFS cluster, part of the datanodes are also HBase regionservers, but others aren't. We would like to run the HBase scans only in the regionservers (to take advantage of the data locality), and run the other type of jobs in all the datanodes. Is this idea possible at all? Can we specify which tasktrackers to use in the MapReduce job configuration?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to specify this, as it would interfere with the jobtracker.  The only way I could think of would be to implement a custom scheduler for MR1/YARN.

Comment: I don't think either that you can specify your tasktracker-list per job. I know that you can exclude tasktrackers by using the `mapred.exclude` and `mapred.include` files, but as far as I know these are only for **all** the jobs running. The functionality that you describe would be really useful!

Comment: Ok, thanks. I suspected it. Using mapred.exclude or mapred.include is not a option.